# Customize Spring Security ResourceServer response

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a spring security config that looks something like what I have below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableConfigurationProperties(OAuthSettings.class)
public class SecurityConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private OAuthSettings oAuthSettings;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        final JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtTokenEnhancer = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        jwtTokenEnhancer.setVerifierKey(oAuthSettings.getPublicKey());
        jwtTokenEnhancer.afterPropertiesSet();

        JwtTokenStore tokenStore = new JwtTokenStore(jwtTokenEnhancer);
        resources.tokenStore(tokenStore);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**")
        .access(String.format("#oauth2.hasScope('%s')", oAuthSettings.getRequiredScope()));
    }
}
```

If I send in a bad token, I get this response:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_token",
  "error_description": "Encoded token is a refresh token"
}
```

I would really like to customize this response.

Example, maybe I'd like to send back an object with a few more (or different) properties. For example a response like:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_token",
  "errorDescription": "Encoded token is a refresh token",
  "aSuggestion": "some suggestion",
  "anotherProperty": "check this out!"
}
```

I am unable to find a hook in spring security to allow me to override this default exception handling behavior. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `commence` method in `EntryPoint`

```
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException;
```

Comment: Okay, doing so now. However, HttpServletResponse seems really limited. Am I able to set a real java object on that response?

Say..

response.setBody(new MyComplexObject());

then let spring serialize this thing to xml or json?

Comment: I afraid not, because it is still in the filter.

Comment: Thanks @chaoluo for the info.

Surely however, this a way to modify the output of a spring security bad token though. 

If this is completely un-configurable, that sure is a serious flaw in spring security.

Comment: @Jeff I have been a while thinking on it, and now I am almost sure that it would make `spring-security` tightly coupled to `spring-mvc`, so I'm sure this is the reason why it does not like that. But maybe you could write your own EntryPoint implementation where you could `@Autowire` the mvc's message converters and use it the way they are used in `spring-mvc`. I have been looking for this, but still have not found a way that fits all my needs.